# I'm trying to replicate some error handling originally created in a google sheet in excel - can't work out the logic

Tags: excel-formula

I need to release a google sheet in multiple formats; .xslx and .ods
Using a google sheet, I naively thought the error handling I created would work in the .xlsx!

I'm creating a risk register and prompting a user to complete entries in Columns E & F, if they're not complete, the user gets a prompt :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg5mR.png)

If entries in columns E & F are not populated then 'Please complete required fields in columns E and F'
If entries in columns E & F are populated - execute the vlookup and return the value

`=IFERROR(IF(OR(LEN(6)=0,LEN(E6)=0, LEN(F6)=0 ),"Please complete required fields in columns E and F",VLOOKUP(G6,'Risk Matrix'!$L$2:$N$10,3)))`

This formula does not work in excel!

I've split the if statement, and the vlookup and they both work individually - I can't seem to combine them in excel - any help appreciated!

Copying the rule from google sheets yields this message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTdMy.png)

Downloading the file as an excel sheet and opening in excel results in a repair which loses the formula

Comment: This is incorrect: `LEN(6)=0` it will always return 1, meaning TRUE. Also it's unclear if you want the lookup as error handling, or in case the IF returns false. You need to close the if and then close the iferror argument.

Comment: Thanks p.b - problem solved. It's amazing how something so small can give such a headache - thanks for your help!